# How can i post a complex JSON object to a server via POST in android?

Tags: android, json, http-post, android-volley

I have complex JSON objects, which I want to post to a server via HTTP POST request.
I have seen many examples with the Volley library, but they all work only with simple key-value pairs (HashMap).
Can anybody advice a library which handles posting of complex JSON objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any reference of library which works with JSONObjcet but I have a working code with AsyncTask here ,which is sending JSONObjects to server :

```
    private class BackgroundOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
            //Your network connection code should be here .
            String response = postCall("Put your WebService url here");
            return response ;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //Print your response here .
            Log.d("Post Response",result);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }

        public static String postCall(JSONObject josnobj) {
        String result ="";
        try {
            //Connect
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(uri).openConnection()));
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();
            //Write
            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
//Call parserUsuarioJson() inside write(),Make sure it is returning proper json string .
            writer.write(josnobj.toString());
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            //Read
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String line = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Now you can call above from from your activity's onCreate() function using below code .

```
   JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
jobj.put("name","yourname");
jobj.put("email","mail");
jobj.put("pass","pass");
    new BackgroundOperation().execute(jobj.toString());
```

Note : Don't forget to mention below permission in your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: 'new BackgroundOperation().execute(jobj.toString());'. AND 'postCall("Put your WebService url here");'. AND 'postCall(JSONObject josnobj)'. Sorry but your code does not make sense.